# Java: How to dynamically fit painted text into window

Tags: java, swing, text, metrics, paint

im trying to paint a big "hello world" on my frame/component.
But i want to dynamically fit it to the window size. So everytime i resize the window the text should perfectly fit into the window.

I use the FontMetrics class to which i assign a font and the measure the widht and height of a character.

But it would be good to have a method i pass the size of a component with a text and the method returns a font i need to use. Well, a font size for a specific font would be enough.

Something like this:

```
public int getFontSizeForDrawArea( int width, int height, String text, Font font) {
  //Pseudo class FontMeasureClass takes a font to do the measures with
  FontMeasureClass measure = new FontMeasureClass( font);

  // method takes size of frame/component and text to return the needed 
  // font size to fit text to frame/component
  return measure.getFontSize( width, height, text);
}
```

I think about making a method which measures the size of a text by trying in a loop until the size is as close as much to the windows widht and height. But maybe there is something ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

One way of measuring the width of your String in pixels is this one:

```
Font myfont = jTextField1.getFont();      
FontMetrics myMetrics = getFontMetrics(myfont);
int width=SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(myMetrics, jTextField1.getText());
```

and here is another one, that calculates additionally it's height in pixels as well:

```
Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10);
FontMetrics myMetrics = new FontMetrics(myFont) {};
Rectangle2D boundsOfString = myMetrics.getStringBounds("Measure this String", null);
int width = (int) boundsOfString.getWidth();
int height = (int) boundsOfString.getHeight();
```

I would do it with the loop you mentioned above.

Comment: Ok still i have to go through a loop and stop when the returned width is the closest to the windows width.

Comment: Yes. The loop should be easy to make. I do not know of any other way.

Comment: Why two answers by same person rather than edit the original answer?

Comment: I'm combining the two answers in one. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the width and paint your text in a big font and resize it down with `Graphics2D.scale`. Usually, the paintComponent-Method receives a Graphics2D object, so you can cast the Graphics object you got into Graphics2D.

Comment: Although Java's font renderer is not particularly good, rendering the text with a different size and later resizing it may result in a much poorer image quality than if the font is rendered with the correct size.

Comment: I understood the question that the OP wants to fit the text at all frame sizes "perfectly". Trying to find the text size that fits best would result in "size jumps" when continually resizing the window. I couldn't think of another way to do this. Also, I think that downscaling of a big text results in a better quality than upscaling of a smaller text. A combined solution would be to find the text size that's just "a bit too large" and then downscaling the text painted in that size a little bit, but I don't know if that looks better.

Comment: As of Java 6, with subpixel AA on, scaling in this way renders perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a loop, but can estimate an appropriate font size after one miscalculation, as most fonts scale proportionally (although fonts may contain different glyphs for different sizes).

E.g. if your painting area is 1000px wide and the computed width for a 100pt font size is 1250px, then a font size of 100pt*1000px/1250px = 80pt should result in a width of 1000px.